# Filename encoding issue in Android project's folder

Tags: android, eclipse, localization

I use MacOS + Eclipse for development for Android. Everything was OK till I tried to use Russian letters for filename in assets/ folder. Any attempts to use non-latin filenames in raw/ folder end up the same...

Eclipse fails to compile with:

```
[2011-11-01 04:27:17 - A....] /Users/user/workspace/A..../assets/–ê–≤–∏–∞—Ü–∏—è.mp3: error: Invalid filename.  Unable to add.
```

Actual  filename is Эхо.mp3

I doubt, that it might be solely Android's issue.....

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue earlier this year with Japanese-named files, except my problem was that a java compare of file names didn't work. The problem had to do with how the mac stores the file names internally (NFD), compared with the representation of file name itself (NFC), which was copied from a different system.

Here's the post:

[Android, problem with file name comparison in Japanese characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784518/android-problem-with-file-name-comparison-in-japanese-characters)

After a wide variety of hassles caused by this, I ended up renaming all my files manually to a much shorter name via the command line. That ultimately solved the problem.